# User assigned roles remain unrecognised

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor, roles, asp.net-roles

I am trying to introduce an admin account into my project. I have updated the *Startup.cs* file to use roles and have added Admin and Standard account inside AspNetRoles and assigned a user using their UserID an admin. The relevant [Authorize(Role = "Admin")] has also been added to the page but the admin account remains denied access. I can't seem to find out what is causing this to not be recognised, I have searched similar posts which suggested implementing

```
.AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
```

However, this did not seem to help either. Would appreciate any insight in resolving this issue. Using Blazor wasm. Thanks in advance.

### Startup.cs

public class Startup
{
public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
{
Configuration = configuration;
}

```
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            
        services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddIdentityServerJwt();

        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddRazorPages();

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

       services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(x => x.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize);

}

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
        });
    }
}
```

### Program.cs

```
 public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
            });
}
```

### AspNetRoles table

[image]

### AspNetUserRoles table

[image]

### Razor pages

```
@attribute [Authorize(Roles ="Admin")]
```

Despite the above implementations, when logging into the assigned Admin account, the message shown is

```
You are not authorized to access this resource.
```

Comment: Could you please display the complete code in your Server's Startup class, and in your Client's Program class. You may delete it later on...Your using Blazor WebAssembly App hosted right ?( Client, Server, Shared)

Comment: Sure! I have updated the most to include it and yes, Blazor Web Assembly hosted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following...

Change:

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
        .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
```

To:

```
// Configure identity server to put the role claim into the id token 
// and the access token and prevent the default mapping for roles in 
// the JwtSecurityTokenHandler.
            
services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>(options => {
                    options.IdentityResources["openid"].UserClaims.Add("role");
                    options.ApiResources.Single().UserClaims.Add("role");
                });
            // Need to do this as it maps "role" to ClaimTypes.Role and causes issues
            JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Remove("role");
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so so much. I was at this for hours! thank you